# My tkinter window does not match the buttons that I want

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

correct_num = random.randint(1,100)
print(correct_num)

def result(num):
    global correct_num,lb
    print(num)
    if num == correct_num:
        lb.config(text='You did it! Congraulations!',fg='blue')
    else:
        if num < correct_num:
            lb.config(text='Guess higher',fg='red')
        else:
            lb.config(text='Guess lower',fg='red')
        
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Guess number')
win.geometry('500x400')

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(1,11):
        number = i*10+j
        button = tk.Button(win,text=number,command=lambda:result(number))
        button.grid(row=i,column=j,padx=10)



lb = tk.Label(win,text='')
lb.grid(row=11,column=5,columnspan=2)
```

For this program, I do not have any errors but when I run, then whatever I pressed any buttons and try to print(num) it shows 100. I would like to put the num corresponding to the button number that I pressed. May I ask is there any mistakes that I have not amended in order to make it work successfully?

Comment: I still cannot find the problem why the number shows 100 when pressing any buttons

Comment: It's because each button calls `result(number)`, and `number` happens to be 100 by the time any button can actually be clicked.

Comment: So what should I change in order to get the number matched?

Comment: This is the third time in the past two hours that I've closed a question about creating buttons in a loop. :-\

Comment: Ok now I could solve the problem